# bonding driver broken on centos6?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, bonding, centos6

I have a server with minimal installation of CentOS6 64bit (minimal option from the installer). The bonding driver does not seem to work correctly. The output from /proc/net/bonding/bond0 is:

```
Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: None
MII Status: down
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
```

The as you can see there are no interfaces listed as salves. The bond driver options were configured in /etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf as:

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 mode=1 primary=eth0 miimon=100
```

Interfaces eth0 and eth4 are configured as such:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
MASTER="bond0"
SLAVE="yes"
HWADDR="78:2B:CB:56:ED:5D"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"

DEVICE="eth4"
MASTER="bond0"
SLAVE="yes"
HWADDR="00:1B:21:C9:F7:38"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

and bond0 is configured as such:

```
DEVICE="bond0"
IPADDR="10.100.46.3"
NETMASK="255.255.254.0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

And here is output from /var/log/messages:

```
Dec  9 08:20:55 app2 kernel: bonding: Warning: either miimon or arp_interval and arp_ip_target module parameters must be specified, otherwise bonding will not detect link failures! see bonding.txt for details.
Dec  9 08:20:55 app2 kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): bond0: link is not ready
Dec  9 08:21:02 app2 kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): bond0: link is not ready
```

Can anyone offer some insight as to why the driver is failing to start? Is this a dependencies issue?

Comment: Have you tried manually executing the ifenslave/ifconfig commands?

Comment: Just tried it now - yes it works if I do it manually. I have always configured CentOS5 as above and it always worked.

Comment: After updating the system the link came up - there must be some bug that needed fixing. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the OS with just sudo yum update fixed the issue. Not sure which part did it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Your log said:

> miimon or arp_interval and arp_ip_target module parameters must be specified

Try to add lines below (you can choose your favourite options) to your ifcfg-bond0:

```
BONDING_OPTS='miimon=1000 mode=6'
```

Comment: From my understanding bonding options must no longer be specified in the interface configuration files as this is no longer supported as of RHEL/CentOS5.